# crash in `[NSApp run]` when delegate is not referenced anymore

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

This is the code:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    printf("My app delegate: finish launching\n");
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {

        [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [NSApp setDelegate:[[AppDelegate alloc] init]];
        [NSApp run];
    }
}
```

It crashes in `[NSApp run]` but I don't really see what I'm missing. If I add an `[NSApp finishLaunching]` before the `run`, it crashes in there.

If I don't set the delegate, it doesn't crash.

If I reference the delegate before, it works fine:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[NSApp setDelegate:appDelegate];
```

So I guess it releases the delegate immediately in the first version because of ARC and because the delegate is probably only a weak reference, right? But how are you supposed to do the same code otherwise?

Comment: Could you try to set the delegate this way: `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:self];`

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv)`?

Comment: @user3125367: Yes (in my case).

Comment: @Albert hmm… the only difference from original implementation is ` [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"whatever" owner:NSApp]` before `run`. Maybe default (or first loading) bundle performs delayed initializations in NSApp?

Comment: I also tried with loading the nib but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's interesting as `NSApplication` declares a `strong` reference to the delegate: `id _delegate;`.

Comment: @trojanfoe: According to the answer, it's a weak ref. Also, that would explain the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you guess right, `NSApplication` don't retain the delegate, (weak reference with ARC).
So you can just build the main.m file with `-fno-objc-arc` with you current code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [NSApp setDelegate:[[AppDelegate alloc] init]];
        [NSApp finishLaunching];
        [NSApp run];
    }
}
```

or set you AppDelegate static in main.m, for example, and build with ARC

```
static AppDelegate* _appDelegate;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        _appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
        [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [NSApp setDelegate:_appDelegate];
        [NSApp run];
    }
}
```